# Add class to elements if scrolled into view but not elements already in view

Tags: jquery, class, scroll, inview

I am using the below code to add a class on a selected element when scrolled into the view-port.

HTML below:

```
<?php
$counter=1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>         
  <div id="archiveItem-<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="mydiv floatLeft">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
     <img src="placement.jpg" alt="">
     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </a>
  </div>            
 <?php
 $counter++;
endwhile; ?>


function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {

    if (!jQuery(elem).length) return false;

    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom >= docViewTop));
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

    jQuery('.mydiv').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this)) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('divshow');
        }
    });

});
```

It works fine but I would like to only add a class to divs that are not in the viewport. It currently adds the class to all divs until scrolled into view.

See example below:

[image]

From the screenshot the first two rows of divs (1-10) should not have the class added as they are in view but the below divs (15-20) are out of view and should have the class added when scrolled into view.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: plz add html code for check

Answer (score 0):

using below code you can check if a div is in view or not and apply classes   accordingly

```
 if( ($(window).outerHeight()+$(window).scrollTop()) > $('#div').offset().top)
 {
      //your code here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Do I add this before the 'each' function?

Comment: Unfortunatly the code given doesn't work. The result is the same. All divs are applied the class.

Comment: @rikardo85 share the jsfiddle if possible

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b95ktfd/4/ - You have to reduce the browser window height to and then scroll to see the boxes appear on scroll.